# Exclusive OR (XOR) in EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Is there a way to do an exclusive or in EL? I have two variables. I want to check if only one of them is empty at a time. I understand I can do this manually by doing the following but I wanted to know if there is an EL keyword for it?

```
<c:if test="${(!empty var1 and empty var2) or (empty var1 and !empty var2}>
    ----Do something here.. 
</c:if>
```

Comment: [Please don't confuse JSTL with EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I've edited the terminology in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EL doesn't have an XOR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html), but since both expressions return boolean already, just compare them by `!=`.

```html
<c:if test="${empty var1 != empty var2}">
    ----Do something here.. 
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean XOR is the same as 'not equal', so use this:

```
<c:if test="${(empty var1) != (empty var2)}>
    ----Do something here.. 
</c:if>
```

[Cannot find an XOR operator here](http://bellsouthpwp.net/b/i/billsigg/jstl-quick-reference.pdf).